# Couchbase 'SKIP' attribute for pagination not working

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

I am working on couchbase-sync-gateway for my new project. I need pagination some of my documents list.

Couchbase pagination attribute "SKIP" not working for me. 
for example my query string is like

```
_all_docs?limit=5&skip=10
```

"LIMIT" is working fine but Skip index always starting from '0'.

I am new to Couchbase. Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated.

Couchbase Documentation link for pagination attributes is http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/references/couchbase-lite/rest-api/database/get-all-docs/index.html

Comment: You are running this against the Couchbase Lite database on your mobile device/ simulator?

Comment: Good catch! Indeed, the skip parameter doesn't seem to be used for generating the response. I've opened a [ticket on github](https://github.com/couchbase/sync_gateway/issues/928).

Comment: @paddy I am using couchbase syn-gateway

Comment: @jamiltz thanks for creating ticket.